# value counts of a Database chunk by chunk using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a big DataFrame df and I want to count each values. I can't do:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('my_big_data.csv')
values_df = df.apply(value_counts)
```

because It is a very big Database.

I think it must be possible to do it chunk by chunk with `chunksize`, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [9]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)
```

Construct a sample frame

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=100000).reshape(-1,1))

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
        0
0      50
1      35
2      20
3      66
4       8
...    ..
99995  51
99996  33
99997  43
99998  41
99999  56

[100000 rows x 1 columns]

In [12]: df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Chunk read it and construct the `.value_counts` for each chunks
Concacatenate all of these results (so you have a frame that is indexed by the value being counts and the values are the counts).

```
In [13]: result = pd.concat([ chunk.apply(Series.value_counts) for chunk in pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,chunksize=10000) ] )

In [14]: result
Out[14]: 
      0
18  121
75  116
39  116
55  115
60  114
..  ...
88   83
8    83
56   82
76   76
18   73

[1000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then groupby the index which puts all of the duplicates (indexes) in a groups. Summing give the sum of the individual value_counts.

```
In [15]: result.groupby(result.index).sum()
Out[15]: 
       0
0   1017
1   1015
2    992
3   1051
4    973
..   ...
95  1014
96   949
97  1011
98   999
99   981

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```